# create a aggregated table in a Time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate-functions, data-science, summary

I have a table and I am trying to calculate how many crashes happen before and after a Fatal crash happened( the event is my Fatal crash) and I want to calculate the total number of crashes one week before and after that fatal crash in each Zone. I appreciate if someone can help.
Thanks so much
[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlwGG.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlwGG.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Crash_Date</th>
    <th>Injury_Stat</th>
    <th>Zone_ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12/9/2014</td>
    <td>No injury</td>   
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>12/10/2014</td>
    <td>No injury</td>   
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>12/12/2014</td>
    <td>Fatal_Crash</td>   
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>12/14/2014</td>
    <td>No injury</td>   
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>12/16/2014</td>
    <td>No injury</td>   
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>12/17/2014</td>
    <td>Non-fatal injury - Possible</td>   
    <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please review [mcve] and, in particular provide an artificial cut-down example of the data sufficient for this problem as well as R code you have tried along with expected output and explanation.

Comment: I put the sample data, but honestly, I don't have any idea about the code.

Comment: Do not post images.  No one can copy them to their R session.